# Running R on Meteor.js mongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, meteor, amazon-ec2

I want to port a MEAN stack app to meteor.js. I need to use R to run a time-series calculation on a bi-weekly basis on the mongodb data. The rest is a CRUD app. I am guessing I can always run a R on an EC2 instance, connect up to mongo, extract the data, do calculations and insert the results. I am worried about performance impact. 
I am thinking about deploying on AWS and using the above approach.

Are there other ways? If I want to deploy the meteor app with Galaxy or Modulus, running R on EC2 is perhaps a bad idea for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not an expert in Meteor.js but I do know different way doing things that does work with express and should work with Meteor, since you have restful endpoints. Basically you could use something similar to https://www.hirefire.io/ or something that polls (bi-weekly) your app at specific Restful endpoints to process your time series calc via R. So lets say the endpoint would be `/timeSeries` . Lastly in your service to respond to the route request invoke R via shelljs. https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs or if you have an R wrapper use that.

Comment: If the data volume is large, extracting and updating mongodb will be an issue, right?

Comment: If there is a wrapper and or you stream the data then you probabaly won't have an issue. But the restful handler for this service should have its own process which is easy to do on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Actually communication between meteor server and meteor client and MongoDB is through DDP (Distributed Data Protocol).
That means you can open a websocket port in R using httpuv and get access to what server sends or what is saved in MongoDB.

Here is what I found:

1. https://www.meteor.com/ddp
2. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md
3. http://info.meteor.com/blog/introducing-ddp